# R:grepl and if combined

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which looks like that:

```
prccd  isin 
2      AR7463
7      AR12345
4      BD5347
5      CF29394
```

Now the goal is to multiply the first column with a number e.g. 5 if the second column is starting with AR and multiply it with e.g. 2 if the the second column is starting with BD and so on. Ho can I achieve that?  I have tried something like that:

```
currencies<-function(GBP,CHF){
  if (grepl("^GB",data$isin)==TRUE){
    data[,"prccd"]*GBP[,"one_GBP_equivalent_to_x_EUR"]
  }
  if (grepl("^CH",data$isin)==TRUE){
    data[,"prccd"]*CHF[,"one_CHF_equivalent_to_x_EUR"]
  }
}
```

But i get the following warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: In if (grepl("^GB", data$isin) == TRUE) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: You are applying grepl to the whole dataframe. It will work if you loop through each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to first 2 conditions, you can substitute in the third condition  whatever you want to multiply with based on the first 2 letters in second column.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(col = case_when(substr(isin,1,2) == 'AR' ~ prccd * 5,
                               substr(isin,1,2) == 'BD' ~ prccd * 2,
                               TRUE ~ prccd * 1))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  prccd isin      col
  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
1     2 AR7463     10
2     7 AR12345    35
3     4 BD5347      8
4     5 CF29394     5
```

Comment: thanks for that, can you maybe explain how this '~' works and when one can use it ?

Comment: Think of it as "then". i.e. in English, case when 'isin' column's first two letters are 'AR' then multiply corresponding 'prccd' column's value by 5.